# me recarga la paina el stopPropagation();

Tags: javascript

buenos dias como hago para hacer que en un evento click de toogle cambie de clases o imagen con flechitas abajo y arriba.

```
 $(document).ready(main);
   var contador = 1;

   function main() {
       $('.children_').click(function() {
           if (contador == 0) {
               $('nav').animate({
                   left: '-100%'
               });
               contador = 1;
               event.stopPropagation();
           }
           return false;
       });
       $('.menu_bar').click(function() {
           if (contador == 1) {
               $('nav').animate({
                   left: '0'
               });
               contador = 0;
           } else {
               contador = 1;
               $('nav').animate({
                   left: '-100%'
               });
           }
           return false;
       });
       $('.info').mouseover(function() {
           $(this).children('.datos').show();
           return false;
       });
       $('.info').mouseout(function() {
           $(this).children('.datos').hide();
           return false;
       });
   }
   $('.child').hide(); //Hide children by default
   $('.parent').children().click(function() {
       $(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow');
       return;
   }).children('.child').click(function(event) {
       event.stopPropagation();
       return;
   });
   $('.child_2').hide(); //Hide children by default

   $('.parent_2').children().click(function() {
       $(this).children('.child_2').slideToggle('slow');
       return;
   }).children('.child_2').click(function(event) {
       event.stopPropagation();
       return;
   });
```

```
<nav>
  <ul class="parent">
  <a  class="children_ nohover" style=" top: 4%;left: -16%;margin-left: 91%;"><span class="icon-cross" style="color: #04223F; font-size: 20px;"></span></a>
    <li class="nohover"><a href="http://www.dominoprofesional.com/" ><img src="http://www.dominoprofesional.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/dominiogrup_logo_.png" style="width: 100%;">

    </a></li>

    <li class="submenu">
      <a  return ="false"><span ></span>UNIDADES DE NEGOCIO<span class="caret icon-arrow-down2"></span></a>
      <ul class="child parent_2">
        <li class="submenu2" style="background: #042240;">
          <a  style="-webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;">SOFTWARE ADAMINISTRATIVO Y CONTABLE <span class="caret icon-arrow-down2" style="top: 0px;"></span></a>
            <ul class="child_2" style="background: linear-gradient(#2BB2E1 , #005D91);">
              <li><a href="http://www.dominoprofesional.com/sac/"> Contabilidad<span class="icon-dot"></span></a></li>
              <li><a href="http://www.dominoprofesional.com/sac/">Tesoreria<span class="icon-dot"></span></a></li>
              <li><a href="http://www.dominoprofesional.com/sac/">Comercial<span class="icon-dot"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

Comment: solo quiero que cierre mi menu normal pero me recarga la pagina

Comment: ya me cierra los submenus peor me recarga la pagina

Comment: Publica la parte del html relevante para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Cuando das click sobre un link, te recarga?

Comment: cuando cierro el menu me recarga la pagina el children_ me cierra el menu  y me cierra los submenus pero me recarga la pagina

Comment: solo quiero que me cierre el menu

Comment: En vez de stopPropagation no seria `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: no por que me deja es menu todo desplegado dentro del menu y lo que quiero es que todo dentro del menu quede cerrado

Answer (score 1):

Los click los haces en anchors sin detener el efecto principal , o sea la recarga, prueba asi:

```
$('.parent').children().click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   ---- resto de codigo ---
});
```

con "preventDefault()" evitas el comportamiento normal del anchor.

Comment: en el anchor ? abro el codigo con un evento de  preventDefault();

Comment: mi error se que esta en esta linea .  function main() {
       $('.children_').click(function() {
           if (contador == 0) {
               $('nav').animate({
                   left: '-100%'
               });
               contador = 1;
               event.stopPropagation();
           }
           return false;
       }); en la parte de  event.stopPropagation(); por que con esto estoy recargando la pagina